# How do I change this generic class, so the main method can work?

Tags: java, oop, generics, jaxb, polymorphism

I have this method in a class

```
 @Override
    public Optional<T> parse (String fileString, Class someClass) {

        File file = new File(fileString);

        Class smclass= new Class();
        try {
            smclass= (Class) getUnmarshaller().unmarshal(file);
        } catch (JAXBException  e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return (Optional<T>) Optional.ofNullable(smclass);
    }
```

and main method:

```
        XmlService xmlParser = XmlServiceImpl.getInstance();
        Optional<class> smclass= xmlParser.parse("File.xml", smclass.class);
        System.out.println(smclass);
```

I want to change the class method so I can call different classes in the main method, not only one, but I don't know how. For example:

```
        XmlService xmlParser = XmlServiceImpl.getInstance();
        Optional<**class**> **class**= xmlParser.parse("xmlFile.xml", **class**.class);
        System.out.println(**class**);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another edit: Removed the type parameter from the method
EDIT(again): If you don't need to instantiate `T`(which I believe you don't), you can do what's below. If the API isn't under your control, then you'll have to write `Class` instead of `Class<T>` and cast.

```
    @Override
    public Optional<T> parse (String fileString, Class<T> someClass) {

        File file = new File(fileString);

        T t = null;
        try {
            t = (T) getUnmarshaller().unmarshal(file);
        } catch (JAXBException  e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return (Optional<T>) Optional.ofNullable(t);
    }
```

If you do need a `Class` object for the unmarshaller to know what kind of object to make, then the only way you can do it is with reflection (that's the nature of the `Class` class. Also, I'm pretty sure JAXB uses reflection internally anyways and it's all unsafe.

Also, it doesn't seem as if you're using `someClass`, so you could probably have a method with only the first parameter. But since you are overriding some method in a superclass, you might just have to try what's above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my main question is:         "Company company = new Company(); " Since I won't have company here, what do I write? I can't make a Class<T> instance

Comment: So I can only get "public  Optional<T> parse (String fileString, Class someClass) "' - the someClass value by reflection ?

Comment: @kpkawaiipkkawaii I deleted my comment. The answer was changed. The `new Company()` part was unnecessary.

Comment: I am unmarshalling XML tags, I need to unmarshall different classes, Company is just 1 class, I have many others, I need to fix my class method because of this. By the way             "company = (T) getUnmarshaller().unmarshal(file);" what should be replaced by company in this case that you wrote?

Comment: Thank you, when I hover on the method I have an error that says: "'parse(String, Class<T>)' in 'service.impl.XmlServiceImpl' clashes with 'parse(String, Class)' in 'service.XmlService'; both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other"

Comment: I am sorry for the spam, I really can't figure it out

Comment: It is under my control yes

Comment: Could I maybe send you the 2 classes and the main method and tell me what is wrong?They aren't long. I am struggling with this for hours, I would be very grateful

Comment: Thanks for submitting an edit. It is only visible to you until it’s been approved by trusted community members - ugh

Comment: Can I post the codes in pastebin? I get this error: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.